# What is difference between adding jar to WEB-INF/lib folder & BuildPath

Tags: jakarta-ee, buildpath, web-inf

What's their(in buildpath jars and in WEB-INF/lib jars) duty?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build path jars are not a part of your web app.
On the other hand, the `WEB-INF/lib` jars are a part of your project.

The advantage of having `WEB-INF/lib` jars over build path jars is that they get bundled into your app when generating a `WAR` file.
This comes in handy when you want to deploy your app on some server where you don't have permission to modify the jars in the build path.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Buildpath jars

- Plus: Help reduce your WAR size, Shared between applications
- Minus:  Class path jar soup - version conflicts

WEB-INF/lib jars

- Plus: Useful to avoid version conflicts
- If you package single application into component jars you
  could prefer to keep it neatly packaged inside WAR